# How to handle elasticsearch script division zero error?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 2.4.1 and need to use inline script to compute field by expression, e.g.

```
POST http://192.168.100.223:9200/bttest/_update_by_query

{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.'503'= ctx._source.'101'/( 
ctx._source.'104'* ctx._source.'105')",
        "lang": "groovy"
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
     {"exists": {"field": "101"}} , {"exists": {"field": "104"}} , {"exists": {"field": "105"}}       ]
        }
      }
    }
```

When there is 0 in the field '105', this execution will fail with exception

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.'503'= ctx._source.'101'/( ctx._source.'104'* ctx._source.'105')] using lang [groovy]"}],"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.'503'= ctx._source.'101'/( ctx._source.'104'* ctx._source.'105')] using lang [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"arithmetic_exception","reason":"Division by zero"}},"status":500}
```

How can I handle this division zero error, I hope it can catch the exception and continue compute field, or set the new field to infinite when meet division zero.

Due to the expression is input by user, so it is not simple to check all the division being zero or not.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the user is writing the script expression himself? That's really not a good idea, unless you don't care much about your cluster integrity.

Comment: @Val Thank you for your comment. Actually the requirement is that user of admin role could add new field dynamically, and the new field could be computed from existing fields.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a workaround. 
add '*1.0' to each field of expression, then it will not report error.

Like

```
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.'503'= ctx._source.'101'*1.0/( 
ctx._source.'104'*1.0* ctx._source.'105'*1.0)",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
```

I think this may related to float handling in Elasticsearch. But not confirmed yet.